# Map a Dictionary<MyClass, string> with (Fluent)NHibernate

Tags: nhibernate, fluent-nhibernate, nhibernate-mapping

I have a class that I need to map that looks a bit like this

```
public class Foo 
{
    public string Name { get; set; }

            // other stuff

    public IDictionary<Bar, decimal> Bars { get; set; }
}
```

my question is how can I map this with NHibernate, I was thinking I can treat the dictionary as a HasMany, since I can recreate a Bar from a string, however it feels a bit crude and I wonder if there is a better way

cheers

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
<map name="Bars">
  <key column="..." />
  <map-key-many-to-many class="Bar" />
  <element type="String" /><!--or decimal, or anything else-->
</map>
```

Answer (score 0):

It depends what the decimal might be, but NHibernate does provide a `<map>` collection type specifically for Dictionary style mappings.

Answer (score 0):

may be this would help: 
[nhibernate-mapping-map](http://ayende.com/blog/4045/nhibernate-mapping-map)